# Separate each file in a different bag from the folder

Tags: apache-pig

I am using PIG LATIN for the analysis of previous T20 WORLD CUP matches. So every match is in a separate CSV file. And I want to find the total no of 100's made by all players.

My approach : I load the each file using this script:

```
t20 = LOAD '/home/ankur/Desktop/Pig_Scripts/t20_csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (inning,overs,team,stk,nstk,bowler,run,extra,type,name);
```

but using this approach each file's data come into the same bag and that's why I can't find the no of 100's.

- If any how each file come into different bag then I can using **FOREACH** . I can calculate.

Is my way of thing is correct or not? Suggest me if you have other idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load all files
2. Filter records where 'run' > 99
3. Count Filtered records

   `t20 = LOAD '/home/ankur/Desktop/Pig_Scripts/*' USING PigStorage(',') as (inning,overs,team,stk,nstk,bowler,run,extra,type,name);
   hundred_records = FILTER t20 BY (run > 99);
   total_hundreds = FOREACH hundred_records GENERATE COUNT(hundred_records);`